# How can I use OAuth with a stateless REST api

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When using Passport, a session is used to transfer the user information. This breaks the statelessness of my REST api.

When `session:false` is used in my auth callback route, I can no longer access the req.user information, due to the reasons outlined above.

How can I use OAuth statelessly on a node/express server?

Comment: Why do you need passport? You're just checking a `Bearer` token right?

Comment: From my understanding, passport makes using OAuth a breeze with various platforms such as Google, Facebook, Twitch, etc...

Comment: I see, you're using other services as your auth provider. I don't have anything to add then.

Comment: I think that my solution might be to use OAuth on the front end with react and once an access token is returned, send it to the server for validation.